# Planned Casino Puzzle

Tags: discussion

Many of you probably know from chat that I have been working on a Casino style puzzle for a while now...

Most of those who do know probably also know that it involves a sort of simulated gambling:

---

For instance I have a Blackjack part. It will show a gif where you and an imaginary opponent receive two cards each, and then it will come up with an option at the end like this:

> ```
> Hit - [Imgur address]
> Stand - [Imgur address]
> ```

If you type in the imgur address for the hit then it will show a gif where you receive another card, etc. and stand you see your opponents cards, etc.

---

Having spent such a long time in creation, I just want to check that this sort of puzzle will be allowed

Some clarifications:

- There is no sort of money or even fake money involved
- There is no reward for winning
- It involves Slots, Bingo, Blackjack and Roulette
- It *is* a puzzle. It has hidden clues throughout

### Will this be OK to post?

Comment: My question is what is the aim of the game?? And is it really a puzzle or just a game of chance??

Comment: @Sid, it has hidden clues within it and it is a puzzle. I'll clarify

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe I can do a sort of vote:

- Upvote this answer if you think this puzzle would be OK to post
- Downvote this answer if you think the puzzle would not be OK to post
- If you are unsure upvote the comment below

Comment: Upvote this comment if you are unsure

Comment: Polls often aren't a good way to get consensus on meta. If it's not OK to post, you'll want to know *why*, and simple downvotes won't tell you that. Likewise, if it *is* OK to post, it'd be nice to see someone explicitly saying so rather than just a bunch of anonymous upvotes which could be from people who like the idea without having a clue about site policy.

Comment: The community here is rather weak: there are only a few regulars around, and sadly most of them are not interested in the decision making processes.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any issue here. There's no problem with the theme of the puzzle, and assuming there's an actual "correct" set of decisions to make (i.e. it's a puzzle and not a game), then there's no problem with the structure either.

In fact, from the sounds of it, it would structurally be the same as [A puzzling image maze!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/a-puzzling-image-maze), so there's already (positively accepted) precedent on your side too.